# Beej's network guide on datagram clients

Tags: c, sockets, datagram

Maybe I haven't fully woken up, but I'm going through Beej's network programming guide on datagram sockets

https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/clientserver.html#simpleserver

and I'm confused by an initial piece in the client side. No command line arguments are specified in the demonstration, however, it looks like there are multiple calls in the code to check for the argument count. For instance, in the first if statement there's a check for the count to be 3, if not the program exits.

```
 if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage: talker hostname message\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Could someone explain what's going on here?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's expecting the program to be invoked with two arguments, "hostname" and "message", which would be `argv[1]`, and `argv[2]` respectively, with `argv[0]` reserved for the name of the executable, `./talker` or the like.

The "talker" program sends a message to the "listener" program, and it needs to know what to send (message) and where to send it (hostname).

Comment: Got it! While the arguments weren't explicitly stated, I could have been smart and looked at the server to see what is was expecting. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're reading the wrong code. The [talker](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html#indexId434909-140) program does indeed take the usual `argc` and `argv` arguments to `main()`.

Comment: I apologize, because I was unclear in my question. I wasn't sure what the command line arguments were supposed to be, but they were answered by meagar. Thank you for your reply.